# Differentiation - del operator

Tags: derivatives, vectors

In one of my textbooks I have come across the following relation:

$G(\vec{x}|\vec{A}) \nabla^2 G_{0}(\vec{x}|\vec{B}) = \nabla \cdot [G(\vec{x}|\vec{A}) \nabla G_0 (\vec{x}|\vec{B})] - \nabla G(\vec{x}|\vec{A}) \cdot \nabla G_0 (\vec{x}|\vec{B})$

I don't quite understand how this relation is derived. I figure it must have someting to do with the product rule for differentiation, but I still don't see how we get, for instance, a negative term. If someone can please show me the steps involved here, then I would really appreciate it!

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Nabla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the scalar Laplacian defined by

$$\nabla^2 G \equiv \nabla \cdot\nabla G.$$

Then, using the product rule for the divergence of a scalar times a vector reveals that

$$\nabla \cdot (G\nabla G_0)=\nabla G\cdot \nabla G_0+G\nabla \cdot \nabla G_0=\nabla G\cdot \nabla G_0+G\nabla^2G_0$$

whereupon rearranging terms gives to coveted result

$$G\nabla^2G_0=\nabla \cdot (G \nabla G_0)-\nabla G\cdot \nabla G_0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it makes complete sense :)!

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the product rule to find 
$$
\nabla \cdot [G(\vec{x}|\vec{A}) \nabla G_0 (\vec{x}|\vec{B})] 
$$
which is the sum of two terms, one of which is 
$$\nabla G(\vec{x}|\vec{A}) \cdot \nabla G_0 (\vec{x}|\vec{B})
$$
Then subtract that term from both sides, to get the relationship you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm afraid I still don't quite follow. Why does the squared del operator even act on the $G(\vec{x}|\vec{A})$ term when the operator is located after this term in the original expression? Is it possible that you can write this out a bit more? I would be extremely grateful!